# Importing a large tsv file to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to import a large one giga tsv file names `bouffe.csv`. It is in ̀ `mongo.../bin` but seems there is a syntax error :

```
> ./mongoimport -d db_name -c collection_name --type tsv --file bouffe.csv -f --numInsertionWorkers 8 --headerline

2017-12-05T22:11:01.064+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' @(shell):1:0
```

I am not able to handle it, I am quite new to this database system.

Here is an overview :

[image]

Comment: Do you call that from the terminal command line? mongoimport should not be called from inside the mongo-shell.

Comment: @Marine1, You are doing (mongoimport) wrong syntax.

Comment: @Marine1, It shuld not be './' before mongoimport statement. As you can see it's already shown error in your error statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marine1,You mongoimport syntax should be like as mention below example.

```
mongoimport --db test --collection stuff --type csv C:\data\Employee.csv --headerline
```

In the above example `test` is `database name`, `stuff` is `collection name` and `Employee.csv` is the file which i want to import in MongoDB database through mongo shell. And the `Employee.csv` file location is `C:\data\Employee.csv`.
In My case it has worked properly.

In your case the syntax should be like that

```
mongoimport --db databasename --collection collectionname --type csv  locationofbouffe.csv  --headerline
```

The syntax should be in the above mention format, if you want to import the `header` of the file then mention `--headerline`.

**Note:-** Make sure you are running the above mention script in inside the `BIN` of MongoDB Server.

**Very Important Note :** `mongoimport would be to import a non-BSON file (such as JSON or CSV) into mongodb.`